# Cannot edit my.cnf file /etc/mysql/ directory because it is a symbolic link. What can I do?

Tags: mysql, symbolic-link

I'm trying to configure mysql but when I type:

```
sudoedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

it says I cannot edit a symbolic link.

Can I remove the symbolic link or change the security settings to allow a symbolic link to be edited?  Does it have anything to do with apparmor restrictions?

Comment: I don't think symlinks actually contain any info besides the pointer to the original file. `sudoedit` probably tries to directly edit the file and doesn't try to follow symlinks, so it doesn't allow you to edit.

Answer (score 5):

That is normal behaviour for `sudoedit` (see `man sudoedit`)

> To help prevent the editing of unauthorized files, the following restrictions are enforced unless explicitly allowed by the security policy:
>
> ```
>              ·   Symbolic links may not be edited (version 1.8.15 and
>                  higher).
> ```

You can edit the file pointed to by the symlink by calling a text editor directly, for example

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

will follow the symlink to the file it points to and allow you to edit that file.

But it would be better to find the regular file by doing

```
readlink -e /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

This will find the regular file pointed to by the symlink, so you can `sudoedit` it, leaving the symlink alone. Applications that read `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` will read the file it points to.